# Leaflet Label noHide no pointer event

Tags: internet-explorer, leaflet, pointer-events

I have to add custom cities name with a `circleMarker` en my map. But I want to clic throu the label because a have polygone under it
There is my JS code thats add the `circleMarker`

```
var ville_label = new L.CircleMarker(
    [lat, lng], 
    { clickable: false, radius: (1/zoom)*12 }
).bindLabel(lib, { noHide: true, className: "leaflet-ville-label" })
.addTo(ville_layer);
```

In CSS I have disable the pointer event

```
.leaflet-ville-label {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

But IE doesn't supprot `pointer-events` and the Label is a div element and not a SVG.

Somebody have a solution to disable pointer events on the static Label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution but not like I think first.

I use a mapbox lib call [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip)

The procedure in detail :

- check click event on all my labels
- do not triger click after map drag (i already had `noclick` on drag start)
- get the mouse Lat Lng with [`mouseEventToLatLng(e)`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events)
- get the polygon with this lat lng
- and finaly trigger click on the result polygon

There is my code to accomplish this :

```
$(".leaflet-ville-label").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("noclick")) {
        $(".leaflet-ville-label").removeClass("noclick");
        return;
    }
    for (layer_id in kml_layer._layers) {
        var under_layer = leafletPip.pointInLayer(france.mouseEventToLatLng(e), kml_layer._layers[layer_id]);
        if (under_layer.length > 0) {
            under_layer[0].fire("click");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Forwarding Mouse Events Through Layers might help you solve this issue. It is kinda workaround for the lack of the pointer-event in ie. Here is a nice blog entry on this issue:

[Forwarding Mouse Events Through Layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)

Comment: Yes I have already test that but `document.elementFromPoint` cant return a map kml element.

Comment: I have missed a point to hide the curretn element. But i now have a `path` or a `g` element. Can you get the polygone from this ?

Comment: Here is kinda function i found for converting a path: http://whaticode.com/2012/02/01/converting-svg-paths-to-polygons/

Comment: I mean the leaflet polygon. I can see the generate svg code by leaflet but a have no event attache to it.

Comment: This method does not seem to work with my layer data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do more than this.

As explained in [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements) , IE 9 and 10 will forward events as long as the background of the label is transparent. 
IE 11 and other browsers adhere to

```
.leaflet-ville-label {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/LHL82/7/

Comment: Edit: I just read that IE 11 adheres to `pointer-events:none`, too. This means I cannot check the transparancy for IE on my home PC. Will check for IE<11 tomorrow.

Comment: I need this site to be compatible IE 8+ This solution doesn't work on it. Or I did it wrong.

Comment: Looks like it's IE9 and up.

Comment: I can confirm this soloution will not work with IE, especially if you need the background or borders non-transparent.